# Current date UPDATE statement not working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, getdate

I'm trying to update a column named `dattime` that is a `date` column (not a datetime column like the name would lead you to believe) in my table named `pr-pre-a` with the current date. I'm using SQL Server 2012 and when I use:

```
UPDATE pr-pre-a 
SET [dattime] = getdate()
```

the `getdate()` is not bolded meaning it is not a recognized command, and when I try to run it, it tells me there is a syntax error. however when I use:

```
UPDATE pr-pre-a 
SET [dattime] = current_timestamp
```

it is bolded, but it still says there is a syntax error. What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: What's wrong with using `current_timestamp` ?

Comment: when i use it it in the exact format above it gives a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to escape `-` in your table name using `[]`

```
UPDATE [pr-pre-a] 
SET [dattime] = getdate()
```

Comment: this worked, i dont know why cause ive never needed to do that before, but it worked

Comment: @SamQL: you need the square brackets if your table name contains dashes, and/or begin with a number (instead of a letter)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your table name in []?

I don't think SQL Server likes hyphens in table names without the square brackets or double apostrophes.